# Preventing overflow on aggregated measures

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssas

According to links below, there is an issue with SSAS that produces silent overflowing on aggregated measures:

http://gqbi.wordpress.com/2013/08/14/ssas-getting-a-negative-value-for-measure-that-has-been-used-in-a-sum/

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/01dc2413-e2f8-4d40-88fa-2faeb4f5dd1b/

Is there a way to preventing that by programmatically changing source's DataType according measure's AggregationFunction property? My intention is to "shift" types to another greater type when required. That is, I want to know whether I need to perform this change for every AggregationFunction or not.

Answer (score 0):

There is no automatism anywhere to prevent this. You just would have to know if the maximum value that can result from aggregation may be bigger than the data type that you are using allows, e. g. if you use a `smallint`, if all aggregated values are between `-2^15 (-32,768)` and `2^15-1 (32,767)`, or between `-2^31 (-2,147,483,648)` and `2^31-1 (2,147,483,647)` for `integer`. All data types have their restrictions.

In case of the mostly used aggregation `sum`, a simple case is if you only have positive or zero values as input. In this case, just sum all values up using a larger data type, check if the sum fits into the type. In case you have some positive and some negative values, the situation is more complex: you would have to separately sum only the positive and only the negative numbers in order to see if any sum may be below the minimum or above the maximum value.

And for other aggregations, the situation will differ.